# How to compile sendxmpp perl script in Cygwin

Tags: perl, cygwin, xmpp

I have been using telnet to issue test commands to my Jabberd2 server. It is a clunky method, so I downloaded the sendxmpp package included with my build of Cygwin. When I issue the command `sendxmpp -h` I get the following error(minus the @INC path dump): `can't locate Authen/SASL.pm in @INC BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/bin/sendxmpp line 21.`

I think the problem is ldap related, however I have installed all of the perl and ldap modules available.

1. Does anyone know how to fix this error?
2. Are there additional configuration steps needed to get ldap working
   with perl in the Cygwin environment?
3. Is there a better way to issue xmpp commands to Jabberd from the
   command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the Authen::SASL module. If it's not part of the sendxmpp package, try installing it with `cpan -i Authen::SASL`. If it IS available, make sure sendxmpp (which may very well be a perl script) finds it, by modifying the inc/lib directory. If `Authen::SASL` is supposed to be installed and available systemwide, try executing `perl -MAuthen::SASL`. If that triggers an error, perl can't find it. If it just "hangs" there (waiting for input), perl did find the module, and sendxmpp should work.

Comment: Turned out I needed sha1 and xmpp as well. After I got all of them built it worked fine. Thanks.